# FlutterAppRequiredException: The current directory does not appear to be a Flutter application project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, exception, mobile

i have install firebase tools for implement it in flutter, i followed all the instruction but when i run "flutterfire configure" this error appears (FlutterAppRequiredException: The current directory does not appear to be a Flutter application project.)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please provide your `pubspec.yaml` ? This way other users will have enough details to intensify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to first redirect to your application path in `CLI`

```
cd app_name
```

Try again `flutterfire` configure command after that.

Answer (score 4):

You must make sure that in your pubspec.yaml the following lines are on the start of dependencies place, ex:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your pubspec.yaml file is well defined and correct.
In my case, I had erased after dependencies

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  ...
```

The correct format may be in flutter 3.3.0 [Flutter and the pubspec file](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec)

```
name: myapp
version: 1.0.0+1
publish_to: none
description: A new Flutter project.
environment: 
  sdk: '>=2.18.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies: 
  cupertino_icons: 
 
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
 
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Close the Project

2- Android Studio > File > Open
(And Open your Project again)

3- Try again `flutterfire configure`

It should be Working Fine Now, the issue is that you opened the new project but
Android Studio didn't redirect to your application path.